# Import data from Azure SQL to HDInsight (text file)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-hdinsight

I have been trying to import data from my SQL Azure DB which is publicly available into HDInsight. Both are part of same subscription.

I fire following query at the HDInsight Command prompt:
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://****.database.windows.net;username=****@fyvgwz1l7z;password=****;database=dbAMBER"
--table dummy --target-dir /data -m 1

It gives no message on the prompt and returns the prompt back. when i browse the location, i find nothing. I also tried to manipulate the sql server address and put some dummy text and isntead of throwing an exception, it still does not give me any message and returns a blank.

Can someone point out issue with what i am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was with the sqoop import command as i fire in hdinsight command prompt. Instead of executing just sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://................ on executing sqoop.cmd import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://...... it worked file. Difference is the suffix .cmd after sqoop command.

Answer (score 0):

I reconstructed your issue and tried it with a freshly created HDInsight Service. I used exactly your query with my own connection-string and it worked out of the box!

I use the Hadoop Command Line Shortcut, browsed to c:\apps\dist\sqoop-1.4.2 and ran your command.

The output was as followed:
[image: Output1]

Even in case of error (fantasy connection-string) i get output:
[image: Output2]

Do you changed some environment settings? Do you have any idea, why your echo is suppressed? How much time does it take for the console to prompt back? Even in case of an error it took about 15 seconds of run-time.

Comment: The issue was with the sqoop import command as i fire in hdinsight command prompt. Instead of executing just sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://................ on executing sqoop.cmd import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://...... it worked file. Difference is the suffix .cmd after sqoop command.